# WPF - MVVM : Bind on method with parameter depending on datacontext property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Here's my problem : I have a DataGrid with a list of objects as DataSouce. In one column, I need to display several images. These images are issued from a property (named Images) of my objects and I have to filter them using a method from my viewModel.

Here's my XAML :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyMethodToFilterImages}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Source}"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>   
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

So, how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a small class that implements  the IValueConvertor and use that part of your binding. Search in the google for IValueConvertor for raio buttons or enums, it has the similar principle that you need to filter the images.

Comment: sorry but I did not understand your problem exactly. so you have one dataGrid in which one column is image column where in each cell will have multiple images ?

Comment: Is the filtered list of images within each instance of "MyObject" or inside the viewModel that contains "MyObjects" ?  Guessing the latter, but just confirming.   Also does the filter need to happen via a method or can it be done once and the filtered list placed in a dependency property?